# Cannot get page token anymore after my page moved to new experience

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I call the following url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<page id>?fields=id,name,access_token&access_token=<long lived user token here>
```

I only get back the fields id and name, but not the field access_token:

```
{
    "name": "<page name here>",
    "id": "<page id here>" 
}
```

Why is that? How can I get the page token with new experience?

Comment: It should still work the same way. What do you get, when you request `/USER-ID/accounts?fields=id,name,access_token` with that same token?

Comment: When I call "accounts" I only get back the pages that are not migrated to new experience. Whereas the pages that are migrated are ignored by the "accounts" api.

Comment: What happens when you have the user remove the app from their settings, and then make them login and grant the necessary permissions again - any change?

Comment: yeah, it looked like I didnt grant permissions to all pages. I can see all of them now..